# map.fitBounds(bounds) causing browser to freeze

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

**I have a really strange error that keeps causing my browser to just freeze when I try to resize a map to fit the markers I have placed on it.**

My resize code for reference:

```
 function sizeMap() {
            // create a new bounds object to define the new boundry
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            // loop through each the string latlang values held in the latlng
            // aray
            for ( var i = 0; i <latlngArray.length ; i++) {
                // create a new LatLng object based on the string value
                var tempLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngArray[i]);
                // extend the latlng bounds based on the new location
                bounds.extend(tempLatLng);
            }
            //  map.fitBounds(bounds); <== everything seems to work fine until this line is uncommented 
        }
```

**Problem is I cant debug it properly using firebug because that freezes to!
Any one got any ideas on what the problem may be?**

Thanks in advance.

Update:

In answer to puckheads question the following code shows where the latlng array is populated to start with:

```
function geocodeAddress (address) {
           
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( {'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    loadMarker(results[0].geometry.location,"Info here",address);
                    latlngArray.push(results[0].geometry.location); <== latlngs are first added here they are as a result of a call to the google geocode service with a standard string address.
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " +" "+  status);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Did you solve the question? - if so you should accept or write your own correct answer!

Comment: Did you try with Chrome and the javascript console?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is as others have mentioned, that you try to create a LatLng object with another LatLng object as argument. It only accepts 2 or 3 arguments, where the two first are numbers. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

However you can entirely skip the part where you create a new LatLng object, and use the current one from your array inside the loop.

This fixes the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/y9ze8a1f/1/

```
function sizeMap() {
    // create a new bounds object to define the new boundry
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // loop through each the string latlang values held in the latlng
    // aray
    for ( var i = 0; i <latlngArray.length ; i++) {
        // This is causing the issue, you can only create a LatLng with two separate latitude and longitude arguments
        //var tempLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngArray[i]);

        bounds.extend(latlngArray[i]);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

If you would want to create a new LatLng based on the old one though, you could do that by using the LatLng methods `lat()` and `lng()`

http://jsfiddle.net/q7sh4put/

```
function sizeMap() {
    // create a new bounds object to define the new boundry
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // loop through each the string latlang values held in the latlng
    // aray
    for ( var i = 0; i <latlngArray.length ; i++) {
        // create a new LatLng object based on the string value
        var tempLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngArray[i].lat(), latlngArray[i].lng());

        // extend the latlng bounds based on the new location
        bounds.extend(tempLatLng);
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Comment: But here the main problem was "it is causing browser to freeze". And it was because of script was long running in the cycle... I marked it with bold, to see it better.

Comment: I know, and the reason for it freezing was maximum callstack reached multiple times, which came from instantiating ´google.maps.LatLng´ with the wrong argument. So the actual code that made this happen was inside Google's code, but was caused by the code calling it. (Your original code where callstack is reached: http://jsfiddle.net/y9ze8a1f/2/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't create a [LatLng](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) object from a single string parameter. If you have a string in the form "lat, lng", then split them apart before creating the LatLng object. The inside of your loop would look like this:

```
        var tempLatLng = latlngArray[i].split(',');
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(tempLatLng[0], tempLatLng[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a magic location that freezes google maps completely. `lat: any, lng: -90`. Everything you can is to omit this values as follows:

```
let lng = position.lng();
if (lng > -90 - 0.001 && lng < -90 - 0.001) {
  lng = -90 - 0.001;
}
bounds.extend(
  new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat(), lng)
);
```

Created issue for google map https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/280958696.

Answer (score -1):

You don't create a new LatLng from a string. It is created from 2 numbers, although it appears 2 strings will work too, one for the latitude and one for the longitude. One string will not work.

So you can say `new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922)` or even `new google.maps.LatLng('-25.363882', '131.044922')` but not `new google.maps.LatLng('-25.363882, 131.044922')`
So you need to pass 2 separate values to new google.maps.LatLng but it appears you are only passing one.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng

Comment: I have tried Marks suggestion and the result is the same, Ive also tried converting the two resultant strings to floats using  parseFloat() and still no joy.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is in latLngArray?

Answer (score -1):

Based on your updated code, you do not need to create tempLatLng at all. Your array already contains LatLng objects so you should be able to say `bounds.extend(latlngArray[i])` in the for loop...

Comment: Tryied your suggestion and the focus is'nt being set but it has stopped freezing thanks puckhead, at least I can debug it now.

Comment: What do you mean by focus isn't being set? Is the issue in question solved?

Comment: Sorry probably did'nt explain my self to well, what I mean is that the browser is no longer freezing but that the view port is not resizing to the bounds of the markers as it should.

Comment: Can you provide more/updated code? Where are map and latLngArray created and sizeMap called? A link would be really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Use Timer:

```
var Timer="";
    $(window).resize(function() {
        clearInterval(Timer);
        run_timer();
    });
    function run_timer() {
        Timer = setInterval(function(){sizeMap();}, 1500);
    }
    function sizeMap() {
        clearInterval(Timer);
        // create a new bounds object to define the new boundry
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        // loop through each the string latlang values held in the latlng
        // aray
        for (var i = 0; i <latlngArray.length ; i++) {
            // create a new LatLng object based on the string value
            var tempLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlngArray[i]);
            // extend the latlng bounds based on the new location
            bounds.extend(tempLatLng);
        }
        //  map.fitBounds(bounds); <== everything seems to work fine until this line is uncommented 
    }
```